# Short URL's not working in WAMP

Tags: php, .htaccess

Copied my live site to localhost for testing purposes. Clean URLs not working.

•   Test site using WAMP.

•   Site coded using PHP.

•   rewrite_module enabled.

•   My htaccess file is on the root folder of the test site.

•   htaccess working to an extent i.e. I am able to open the home page. Not able to use clean URLs in the menu.

•   Error message when using other links from the menu i.e. ‘our-services’: “Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)”

•   Browser message: The requested URL /our-services-test.php was not found on this server. htaccess as follows:

```
RewriteOptions inherit
Header unset ETag
FileETag None
Options -Multiviews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^http://localhost/
RewriteRule ^our-services$ //our-services-test.php [L]
```

Can anyone help to find out the issue?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^our-services$ our-services-test.php [L]`

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
RewriteRule ^our-services$ /our-services-test.php [L]
```

With only one `/`

Answer (score 0):

Changed a couple of lines. Now working, all good:

RewriteOptions inherit

Header unset ETag

FileETag None

Options -Multiviews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase / mywebsite /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^http:// localhost/mywebsite/

RewriteRule ^our-services$ / mywebsite /our-services-test.php [L]